# Como realizar acciones en con el programa a la espera de input (Python )

Tags: python

La pregunta es muy sencilla ...

```
numero = input('Introduce un numero -> ')
print(numero)
```

-En este ejemplo, existe la posibilidadad de realizar acciones mientras el usuario no introduce nada, algo asi como ...

```
 while True:
    entrada = funcion_que_estoy_buscando()
    if entrada == None: 
       print('Pulsa algo ...')
```

-Y que esto devuelva algo como ...

```
Pulsa algo...
Pulsa algo...
Pulsa algo...
(Hasta que pulse algo)
```

Comment: Ahora no puedo probar mi código, cuando pueda publico una respuesta, investiga sobre el módulo `pynput` y `keyboard`

Comment: Bien, gracias!!

Comment: @Christian el problema con pyinput y keyboard es que si la ventana de cmd está minimizada y apretas una tecla, el programa detectará la pulsación igualmente. Es decir, aun cuando la ventana está desenfocada, se siguen detectando pulsaciones de teclado.

Comment: @DanteS es verdad, pero no se me ocurrió otra idea para su problema, así que de momento es una opción, no digo que sea la solución